# How To Play Video File Using Asp.net Flash Video Control?

Tags: asp.net

Can u pls tell me How To play the Video File Using Flash Video Controller in asp.net.
i'm Getting the Saved Video Path but it didn't play the video.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't pasted **What you have tried**, answer will be based on assumption :)

If you are using [AspNet Flash Video](http://www.aspnetflashvideo.com/aspnetflashvideo_Default.aspx), then this is how I am running it.

```
<ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideoDemo" runat="server" Alignment="Center"></ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
```

And in your code behind file, set its source as:

```
FlashVideoDemo.VideoURL = "~\Resources\Sample.flv"
```

This is working for me. If it doesn't help, try pasting your code.

Thanks